# Array not inserting object correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a website. I am trying to add a "Warn" feature, but when I store the warn into a user, I get this: `0: 1`

Here is what I mean by `0: 1`
So, here is my code... The variable that is causing this problem is `newUser[0].warn = newWarn`

```js
const newMsg = {
        title: msg[0].title,
        body: msg[0].body,
        author: msg[0].author,
        postid: msg[0].postid
    }
    const warn = newUser[0].warn
    const newWarn = warn.push(newMsg)
    console.dir(newMsg)
    newUser[0].warned = true
    newUser[0].warn = newWarn
    await newUser[0].save()
```

Btw, newMsg is set correctly:
[image]

And here is where it says `0: 1`

[image]

[image]

This is supposed to be storing `newMsg` in an array, while keeping the other contents in the array.

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**

I found the problem, but I am unsure how to fix it.

It has to do with `const newWarn = warn.push(newMsg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because warn.push return the array of length which is actually 1

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push